# Show $[TA] \times [AB] =[TB] \times [BC]=[TC] \times [CA]$ by vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry, equivalence-relations

Let $T$ be the centroid of a triangle $\triangle ABC$.

How can I prove that (using vectors):

$$\overrightarrow{TA} \times \overrightarrow{AB} =\overrightarrow{TB} \times \overrightarrow{BC}=\overrightarrow{TC} \times \overrightarrow{CA} $$
($\times$ is for vector-product).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\text{Noting that}\\[4pt]
\overrightarrow{TA}=\;&\frac{\overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B}+\overrightarrow{C}}{3}
\\[6pt]
&\text{we get}\\[6pt]
\overrightarrow{[TA]} \times \overrightarrow{[AB]}
=\;&(\overrightarrow{A}-\overrightarrow{T})\times(\overrightarrow{B}-\overrightarrow{A})\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\overrightarrow{A}-
\left(
\frac{\overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B}+\overrightarrow{C}}{3}
\right)\right)\times(\overrightarrow{B}-\overrightarrow{A})\\[4pt]
=\;&\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{3}}}\bigr)(
2\overrightarrow{A}-\overrightarrow{B}-\overrightarrow{C})
\times(\overrightarrow{B}-\overrightarrow{A})\\[4pt]
=\;&\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{3}}}\bigr)(
\overrightarrow{A}{\times}\overrightarrow{B}
+
\overrightarrow{B}{\times}\overrightarrow{C}
+
\overrightarrow{C}{\times}\overrightarrow{A}
)
\\[6pt]
&\text{Similarly, we get}\\[6pt]
\overrightarrow{[TB]} \times \overrightarrow{[BC]}
=\;&
\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{3}}}\bigr)(
\overrightarrow{A}{\times}\overrightarrow{B}
+
\overrightarrow{B}{\times}\overrightarrow{C}
+
\overrightarrow{C}{\times}\overrightarrow{A}
)\\[6pt]
&\text{and}\\[6pt]
\overrightarrow{[TC]} \times \overrightarrow{[CA]}
=\;&
\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{3}}}\bigr)(
\overrightarrow{A}{\times}\overrightarrow{B}
+
\overrightarrow{B}{\times}\overrightarrow{C}
+
\overrightarrow{C}{\times}\overrightarrow{A}
)\\[4pt]
&\text{which proves the claim.}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}